# Restoring components of a categorical product of morphisms

Tags: category-theory

Can two morphisms (say of the category Set, but also in every category with binary product) be restored knowing a product of these two morphisms?

I'm especially interested in the case if one of the morphisms is empty, e.g. is the morphism from an empty set to an empty set.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to understand morphisms $Y \to X_1 \times X_2$, morphisms $X_1 \times X_2 \to Y$, or morphisms $Y_1 \times Y_2 \to X_1 \times X_2$?

Answer (score 1):

By the very definition of a categorical product, $f_i = \pi_i \circ f$ where $f$ is the product of $f_1, f_2$, so it's always possible to recover the morphisms. If one of them is empty, for example $f_1 : Y \rightarrow X_1 \times X_2$ is empty, then it means that $Y = \varnothing$, and the other function must be the empty function too, and $f_1 \times f_2 = \varnothing$ too.

In general, if $Y$ is the initial object of $\mathcal{C}$ (like $\varnothing$ is the initial object of $\mathcal{Set}$), then in the commutative diagram defining the product, the morphisms $f_i : Y \rightarrow X_i$ are the only morphisms from $Y$ to $X_i$, and their product $f$ is the only morphism from $Y$ to the product of the $X_i$.

Comment: Sorry for a stupid question, but why $\pi_i$ are unique?

Comment: They are not "unique", but they are part of the product: in category theory, the product of $X_1$ and $X_2$ is a object $X$ *together* with two morphisms $\pi_i : X \rightarrow X_i$ that make the usual commutative diagrams commute. See here for reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)